# "Не судьба" в прошедшем времени

Tags: фразеология, выбор-слов

Увидел в книге фразу ***не судьба была*** (что-то сделать). Речь о прошлом.

*Так можно говорить? И, если нельзя, то как быть: вообще не употреблять это выражение в прошедшем времени или употреблять как-то иначе? (Как?)*

Comment: Вполне употребимо. И на этом сайте в том числе: «Пусть этим озадачиваются... составители циркуляров (если какой-то фразе не судьба под какое-то их правило подпасть)».

Comment: Тут-то не прошедшее время! Но Жасмин меня убедила, что это и в прошедшем нормально.)

Comment: Совершенно нормально выглядит, синонимично "(ему) не светило" (добиться в этом успеха и т. п.).

Comment: Точно, Александр!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Нацкорпусе 23 примера:

Решительно ему **не судьба была** купаться в этот сезон, по крайней мере в Гурзуфе. [Дмитрий Быков. Орфография (2002)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5+%F1%F3%E4%FC%E1%E0+%E1%FB%EB%E0

Comment: Спасибо, Жасмин! Не догадался сам там глянуть.